# ui-router change, when to remove the old html

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've tested this in chrome, and added a break in the `$scope.init` in `Ctrl2`
but then when I go to `route2` from `route1`, the chrome debugger stays at `$scope.init` of `Ctrl2`, but I see that `ctrl1.html` is still there.

```
.state("main.route1", {
  url: "/route1",
  controller: 'Ctrl1',
  templateUrl: 'views/ctrl1.html'
})

.state("main.route2", {
  url: "/route2",
  controller: 'Ctrl2',
  templateUrl: 'views/ctrl2.html'
})
```

So, how does the ui-router work?  Isn't it supposed to go to `ctrl2.html`, and then execute `Ctrl2`?  Why did it enter `Ctrl2` but the `ctrl1.html` is still displayed?

I'm not sure if it is the same in `ng-view`, I haven't tested that.

Comment: can you add the html, or create a plunker

Comment: In UI router, the controller runs as part of the state transition. You are not _in_ the state until all transition thereto is complete.

Comment: controller has to initialize before angular worries about there being any html in order to create the scopes for the DOM. That can be happening while the templates are fetched

Answer (score 0):

1. Check js console to make sure you don't have errors in your angular controller
2. Add following `run` block to your module to catch state change error

   ```
   .run(function ($rootScope, $state) {
       $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
           function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
               console.log(fromState.name + ' to ' + toState.name);
           });
       $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', 
           function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
           alert(error);
           event.preventDefault();
       });
   });
   ```